# How do I programatically change Locale in Flutter when using MaterialApp.router()

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I have:

```dart
final themeMode = context.select<PreferencesChangeNotifier, ThemeMode>((notifier) => notifier.themeMode);
final locale = context.select<LocaleChangeNotifier, Locale>((notifier) => notifier.locale);

return MaterialApp.router(
  locale: locale,
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  scaffoldMessengerKey: MyApp.rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
  routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
  routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
  title: 'MyApp',
  theme: AppTheme.instance.lightTheme,
  darkTheme: AppTheme.instance.darkTheme,
  themeMode: themeMode,
);
```

But this only sets the initial `Locale` and even though MaterialApp gets rebuilt when `locale` changes, it does not reflect the change.

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization#overriding-the-locale), this is done using `Localizations.override()`

But I cannot put `Localizations.override()` above the `MaterialApp`, since localizations are not in its `BuildContext`.

I am completely lost where should I set the desired locale. The only thing I could think of is to override the locale on each screen, which seems hacky and I assume two sets of localizations would need to be loaded in such case.

Answer (score 0):

MaterialApp maybe not rebuilding when value of locale changes.

use a `ValueListenableBuilder` that listens to changes in the locale value
and then rebuilds a materialApp

```
return ValueListenableBuilder<Locale>(
 valueListenable: locale,
 builder: (context, locale, _) {
   return MaterialApp.router(
     locale: locale,
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     scaffoldMessengerKey: MyApp.rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
     localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
     supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
     routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
     routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
     title: 'MyApp',
     theme: AppTheme.instance.lightTheme,
     darkTheme: AppTheme.instance.darkTheme,
     themeMode: themeMode,
   );
 },
);
```

Comment: Been there, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself with a workaround to the problem, I am still looking for a better solution:

I wrapped the MaterialApp widget with a key dependent on Locale, so that the MaterialApp effectively restarts when the Locale changes:

```dart
final locale = context.select<LocaleChangeNotifier, Locale>((notifier) => notifier.locale);
return KeyedSubtree(
  key: Key('myApp-$locale'),
  child: MaterialApp.router(...),
);
```

I then had to add a locale dependent key to a few other places as some widgets persisted and got reattached to the new MaterialApp tree. It's a bit fragile solution, but seems to work for now.